# Odd behaviour from Array in BinaryHeap

Tags: d, phobos

I have a tree-like structure using `Node` objects with references to other `Node` objects. `Node` is a class. Now, one of the routines I'm writing needs a minimum priority queue, which I'm implementing using `std.container.BinaryHeap` and `std.container.Array`. I'm instantiating it as follows:

```
Node[] r;
auto heap = BinaryHeap!(Array!(Node), "a > b")(Array!Node(r));
```

As part of the routine, I insert elements into `heap` using `insert` and remove elements from it using `removeAny`. Now, the routine works correctly, but afterwards, the tree-like structure breaks (my invariants for it fail), due to nodes being missing. What's going on here and why is this happening?

Comment: Is `Node` a clas or struct?

Comment: It's a class. I've edited my original post to make this clear.

Comment: can you post a minimal sequence of calls that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: As per request, here is a minimal sequence of calls that reproduces this behaviour. This clearly shows nodes are missing from the structure: https://gist.github.com/mrsinister13/9821806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=6998 - std.container.Array destroys class instances

Comment: This was reported in 2011-12 and *still* hasn't been addressed? That's a bit of a worry - I suspected that was the problem. Short of brute copying, is there any way around this? I'm using ``Array`` for ``BinaryHeap`` and no other reason, so is there a way I can avoid it?

Comment: For anyone who is watching - it appears the issue was fixed about 14 days ago.